# php, поиск элементов в массиве по маске ключа

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

PHP 5.3

Есть ассоциативный массив с множеством элементов. Надо из этого массива вытащить значения всех элементов с ключами соответствующими шаблону (регулярка).

Пример массива:

```
<?php
$array = [
    'name'     =>'vasya',
    'city'     =>'Kazan',
    'age'      =>18,
    'param1'   =>23.5,  // <-
    'param2'   =>5,     // <-
    'param17'  =>11,    // <-
    'param9'   =>0,     // <-
    'paramid9' =>2,     // мимо
    'level'    =>3,
    ....
]
```

Соответственно надо вытащить все значения, у которых ключи попадают под регулярку `/^param\d+$/`

В принципе ничего сложного нет, но мне не нравится мое решение. Может кто сможет предложить более элегантное?

Моё решение:

```
<?php
$result = array_values(
              array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(
                      preg_grep('/^param\d+$/', array_keys($array)))));
```

Comment: да уж действительно, могли бы обойтись одним циклом с проверкой ключа, нежели четырмя в функциях

Comment: @teran а вот не скажите. В моем варианте всего одна операция поиска по регулярке, да и built-in функции обработки массива вполне могут работать быстрее чем цикл по каждому элементу

Comment: дак вы проверьте сначала, что действительно быстрее будет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среди функций работы с массивами присутствует и функция фильтрации [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php), которая отсеивает элементы массива с помощью ф-ии обратного вызова. callback-функция в зависимости от флагов может принимать либо значения, либо ключи либо пару ключ-значения фильтруемого массива. В нашем случае использование флага `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` (**php 5.6**) определяет передачу только ключа.

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($key){
                 return preg_match("/^param\d+$/", $key);
             }, 
             ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Альтернативой будет ручная фильтрация ключей с помощью обычного цикла:

```
$result = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v){
    if(preg_match("/^param\d+$/", $k)){
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Забыл добавить. К сожалению у меня PHP 5.3, без вариантов

Comment: сорри за ответ через год) при использовании foreach в $k же будут числовые ключи , начиная от 0